# Sound only from Subwoofer, Ubuntu 16.04, Laptop Asus G750

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, asus

When using Ubuntu I can only get sound through the subwoofer underneath the laptop and not from the left and right speakers located between the body and the screen (when open). 
I've tried all remedies and from what I can tell it is a bug with the audio software.

Making any kind of change results in no audio at all.

If anyone knows any fix for this that would be appreciated but as I have already spent hours searching I am sure it is a bug now.

Dual boot with Windows and windows 10 has fully working audio from all speakers.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but if anyone have the same problem with Ubuntu on G750 here is a fix. (Problem is still present in 18.04)

**Problem:**
The head speakers are recognized as "Headphone".
Ubuntu will mute them, if there is no headphone plugged in.
(You can unmute and volume them up in alsamixer)

**Fix:**
You have to force pulseaudio to not mute the channel, if there is no plug in the jack.
To do this, open the analog-output-speaker.conf

```
sudo nano /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-speaker.conf
```

Scroll down to the [Element Headphone] Section and change these lines

```
[Element Headphone]
switch = off
volume = off
```

to this:

```
[Element Headphone]
switch = mute
volume = merge
```

After reboot or restart pulseaudio (`pulseaudio -k`) 
your sound will work fine.
Thats it - have fun ;-)

Comment: Five years later, this is still relevant for Linux Mint (21.1 Cinnamon). It still sounds a bit odd with them purely blended, like the sub is too loud (perhaps it needs to be filtered down to a LFE channel, but I do not know how to do this.) At least there's some stereo effect though!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `alsamixer` on your command line and find out which channels are de-/activated.

Comment: Would you elaborate on how this should be done?

Comment: Of course, open a terminal and type `alsamixer`, than everything should  be self-explanatory. If you don't have `alsamixer`, get and install it with `sudo apt-get install alsamixer`.

Answer (score 0):

Install alsa tools

> sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
>
> hdajackretask

Internal speaker should be on channel group 1, front. 0x14

Checkmark 'show unconnected pins' and 'Advanced override'

Pin 0x16  (check Override) Connectivity blank, Front Location, Jack unknown, Speaker Device, Channel Group 1, Channel (in group) Center/Lfe

Apply now. Install boot override.

> sudo sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

(add at end of file)

options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode4

> sudo gedit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf

(take out ';' on the line 'enable-lfe-remixing = yes')

ALso, and specify

default-sample-channels = 4
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right,lfe,lfe

Save and reboot computer.

I have a 2.1 configuration (internal speaker Bang & Olfusen and external subwoofer), but in Pavucontrol, I use Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I don't have Pin 0x16 available to me. I will try using this tool though to rework things and see if it can help. Thanks for the tip and detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

[image: hdajackretask]

Also, in alsamixer, press F5 to see your sound levels. Move across with right arrow key. If a level shows 'MM' then press M to un-mute it. If a level is too low, once you are on that channel, press UP-arrow key to increase volume.